# How do I parse data from a button into a form in AngularCLI

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-material

I am trying to utilize a button in my Angular App to provide information to a form on click instead of using radio buttons, select, etc. The goal is to be able to utilize a button so that I can pass HTML into the button (e.g. Mat-Icon). I'm a little stuck at the moment because I have not been able to parse the data into the form out side of radio-buttons, select/options, inputs (excluding "type=button").

I first tried:

```
<div class="flex-wrapper" [formGroup]="subForm">
   <mat-form-field formControlName="resourceName" >   
        <input type="button" *ngFor="let res of resources" [value]="res">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Then I tried:

```
<div class="flex-wrapper" [formGroup]="subForm">
    <mat-form-field formControlName="resourceName">
      <button type="button" *ngFor="let res of resources"[value]="res">
        {{res}}
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

Outside of these two options everything else seems to work in terms of .

Neither work and my preference would be to have the second one working. The form is a subform in a child component of a parent component/form group. It's also utilizing Angular Material Stepper at the parent level.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to create a setter for the data element I wanted to edit.

```
setResource(value:string){
this.subForm.setValue({resourceName: value});}
```

I initiated the code with:

```
(click)="setResource(res)" *ngFor="let res of resources" type="input"
```